# would like to tar files ending with same timestamp in to a single tar

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I got a list of log files and all these files end with a timestamp.
For each day I have bunch of log files all ending with same timestamp
For a week I have long list of file all with time stamps.

The challenge is, I would like to use tar command to archive set of files ending with same timedate stamp as one tar file.

Henc end up with tar files for every day accordingly.

How can I achieve this please? some sort of string matching wild card, I'm new to linux help please.

File Examples:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7R62C.png)

Comment: Please give some example of what the filenames looks like.

Comment: Hi Jona, The link to example screenshot attched

Comment: say for 10 augus 2020, i would have about 40+ files in the format:    FILENAME_20200810_SERIAL.NO.log,  string in caps are variables, & the timestamp changes each day, so using just the time stamp, I would want to tar all the files for that day into one tar file. hence end up with tar file for each day of the month.  please note that all the log files each day are generated into single folder hence the need to not just tar but also sort the tar file as daily backup, some times we would have to revisit the old logs & this will make it easy as to which day tar we can untar for log analysis.

Comment: Is `ls *.20200812_*.log` *listing* all the file you want ?

Comment: FYI, don't post image when you can copy the text into the question.

Comment: yes they do, but i want to avoid typing dates daily, that doesn't serve the purpose, instead, I want tar matching timestamp files into single tar..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, get a list of unique timestamps. Then, for each timestamp archive all files with that timestamp:

```
printf %s\\n *.log | grep -Eo '\.[0-9]{8}_' | tr -d ._ | sort -u | while read timestamp; do
   tar cf "$timestamp.tar" ./*"$timestamp"*.log
done
```

Here I assumed that the timestamps always have 8 digits, always start with `.` and always end with `_` (as shown in your screenshot).

Answer (score -1):

```sh
# get all dates
all_date=`find -type f | awk -F '_'  '{print $2}'`

# make a dir to save tar files
mkdir tarfiles

# archive
for d in $all_date ; do
    tar zcvf tarfiles/$d.tar.gz *$d*
done
```

Comment: well, the date changes daily, so i want to avoid using dates in the script. Just use a matching wild card to club the logs into one tar.   using static dates means that i would have to insert daily dates for next 10years! or may be more..

Comment: I heavily recommend `tar ... *111*` over ```tar ... `ls *111*` ```. The latter is not only slower, but also mangles filenames with spaces and symbols like `*`.

Comment: Code only answers are frowned upon on SO. Quality answers explain essential parts of the code, giving it long term value to future visitors, who can then learn from your code to apply it to their own issues, and thus are more likely to be upvoted.